# Split an input twice

Tags: java, list, split

I'm currently stuck at a problem with a list.
The list looks like this

```
a b c d
a d
a c
d b
...
```

The first line is an index and is removed after it has been used. The rest will be needed later.

```
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
line.add(strLine);
}
//...
line.remove(0);
```

This way a  list ("line") is created.
Now I want to split the list again by removing the spaces.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Use the split function?

Comment: Do u have space line in input?

Comment: do you want `["abcd", "ad", "ac", "db", ...]`?

Comment: Well now the List looks like this ["a b c d", "a d", "a c", "d b", ...] and I'd like to remove the spaces. There is no "ListName".split function though.

Comment: or `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'd', ...]`?

Comment: Exactly like this! ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'd', ...]

Comment: Not [['a','d'],['a','c'], ['d','b'],...]?

Comment: "Not [['a','d'],['a','c'], ['d','b'],...]?" Though that would seem like the logical approach I would like to have two seperate lists / arrays for the left and right letter.

Comment: Can you provide a proper example with input and output in your question?

Comment: a b
     a b
b d
c a

but i need them to be like this array1=(a, a, b,c) ; array2=(b, b, d, a) // I am sorry, but I do not know how to keep the format and not make it beeing shown in one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments, you need

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'd', ...]
```

this list if the input is this:

```
a b c d
a d
a c
d b
...
```

So you figured out how to accomplish this:

```
["a b c d", "a d", "a c", "d b", ...]
```

I'll tell you the further steps. Let this list be `lines`.

Now, loop through all the elements of `lines` and then loop through each character of that element and save the required information in another `List`.

```
for (String line: lines) {
    for (char chr: line) {
        if (chr == ' ') {
            continue;
        } else {
            characters.add(chr);
        }
    }
}
```

Now your `characters` list will look like this

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'd', ...]
```

Comment: !THIS  I am kinda embarrassed that I didn't think of that approach. I thought I'd be way more complicated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Split each line and filter space. Ignore first line in loop:

```
boolean firstLine = true;
List<List<Character>> chars = new ArrayList<>();
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (firstLine) {
        firstLine = !firstLine;
        continue;
    }
    chars.add(strLine.chars().filter(e -> e != ' ').mapToObj(e -> (char) e).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Chars contains the output: [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]

Comment: `[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]`, Is this requested?

Comment: @dude coder yes, at the last comment under question

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly in the comments, you want the following input:

```
a b c d
a d
a c
d b
c a
```

To become the following two lists (with the first line of input ignored):

```
List 1: [a, a, d, c]    (the characters in the first column)
List 2: [d, c, b, a]    (the characters in the second column)
```

Since you already have part of it done (putting the input-lines in a list and removing the first one), I'm just gonna continue from there:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
for(String line : lines){
  String[] splitLine = line.split(" ");
  list1.add(splitLine[0]);
  list2.add(splitLine[1]);
}
```

This splits each line by the space, and puts the first characters in the first list, and the second in the second list.

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##fZPNbtswEITvfIqpTxSKKrGPdhqgQXookMJA3VvgA0XSNR2JFMiVU6Pws7tU9BPFcnIQRO1@uzuzhHZiL77s1NPpZIrSecIuBlLj0rtqs9Feq19aKO0X7Cz9Y/n9r9QlGWfHOVtWtCKvRXGpuiKTp9@8F4cHE@hC7p3wSgpr62aMyVyEgJ/C2H8MKKssNxKBBMXX3hmFIqZ4lGDsn8c1RFJjAPkDmhNQD7lpiFvkxuqAr7D6Gb2ym1ueLFp6ZAnGtvwoxVeHQLpIje3L3y4TmW9r38b5oGLjfKs/@vIPUd8CvD3F4syncaCqv3iS4FNsV@X5AklnD42nVCjVlfW9j2xIeF24vebXMX15NYGmH61mRM8@oge@6vGYNyoGuvtbC2VuqPVbQ@lLgE8w6buhkde47PDH6/UZMDsDpuvRLto7cxWlZZxPueWTWjumc0zwuZnTV71Lz17pWUsfIQXJLR/8MTCuN3x1hd/L@@Uc9w7BFZq29W6eDW2hO551So/seDoJZJBQTLw8kilkTEL8Bw)

If you really need two arrays instead of lists, you could do something like this instead:

```
int amountOfLines = lines.size();
String[] array1 = new String[amountOfLines];
String[] array2 = new String[amountOfLines];
for(int i = 0; i < amountOfLines; i++){
  String[] splitLine = lines.get(i).split(" ");
  array1[i] = splitLine[0];
  array2[i] = splitLine[1];
}
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##jVNNb6MwEL37V8zmZBSVJjmWtFJX7aFSVpE2e4s4GHCayYKN7CHd7Cq/PWuCId9VDwiYeW/mvYdZibW4W2W/dzssSm0IVq4Qog6/V4uFNDL7KUUmTcTO2m/T1z@pLAm1uuypsqIZGSmKa@yKMA@fjRGbCVq61bNXGjfws1QoVW9hLM2FtfBDoPrHAMoqyTEFS4Lcba0xg8K1uNOG6n0egwhqGACZDTRPAPWScYN4ghyVtPAISn5AJ3n8xIPIoy@8AiqPv2jx2caSLEJUHf00ZUiM557W@RFjoY3X73yZidMXAfdPjpyY0C3M6jceBPDNjavyPIKgtQeNp1BkWUvrZm/ZMcLIQq8lH7i2r6MiEIWuFE0XE59Mg7X4Vx5COeRbRzb0nnz1ZEB8nTL6CqVOolaEDjyI3G18Ks6V@v0j390KW@ZIPq9G/rskjkG4b/Ae9Don4C3MMXbgjjgfxGeI0TliGJ@n6r@@rigsnRLKFe/tzxQMH6AH/eaA2ZB0o5Q3q4NDrDcHjD4ZMGoHbCEVlC750a8LqLuA7u/h1/Rl@gAvGqwuJC3rM/aBtATZ4lnrZ8u2u52ABFLImNhfKcsgYSmI/w)

Comment: @DudeCoder Based on [his last comment from 24 minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52368788/split-an-input-twice/52369463?noredirect=1#comment91682535_52368788), that's what he's trying to accomplish.. His actual question description indeed states otherwise, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] strArray = new String[letters.size()];

    strArray = letters.toArray(strArray);

    letters.clear();

    for(String A:strArray) {
        String[] arrOfStr = A.split(" "); 
        for(String B:arrOfStr) {
            letters.add(B);
        }
    }
```

Output will look like this

```
[a, b, c, d, a, d, a, c, d, b]
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 (functional) version:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(filename), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)
        .flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(x.split("\\s+")))
        .collect(toList()));
// or if your data set is large and you don't really need it all in one list:
//      .forEach(doSomethingUsefulWithEachIndividualWord);
```